# Mock Locations option keeps turning off

Tags: applications, 5.1-lollipop

I am trying to test an app i have been sitting on for a while. 
In order to do that i need to use the option "Allow mock Locations", so i set it to on. But as soon as i refresh the page it's gets automatically turned back off every single time. So i am unable to use this option. 
I tried finding if an installed app does effect that but as it turned out was not the problem there. This is the only rooted phone i have so i need to get this working on this device. 
I'm using 5.1.1, OnePlus X

Anybody maybe with a similar problem or any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after posting the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Things you can try:

If testing on an actual device, make sure that you have the "Developer options" turned on, and a check on the "allow mock locations" checkbox.

From the phone's location settings, make sure the location is not gotten by using Wi-Fi and mobile networks, so only "GPS" or in some models "Device Only" checked.

Finally, if you are developing the app yourself and/or have access to it's manifest; check to see that the manifest contains the correct permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

for further help concerning development issues, you can read from this post on stack overflow for assistance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device

I left this answer here for further reference in case it will be useful for others.

Comment: Yea i got that...
The problem is, right after i CHECK the "allow mock locations" it get's UNCHECKED (turned off) again.
P.S. If i did not hade "Developer mode" activated i would not be able to access the screen...

Comment: have you verified that it is only happening for the "allow mock locations" checkbox? for e.g. if you check the "stay awake" checkbox, does it also revert back to default unchecked, or is the problem only occuring with the mock locations checkbox?

Comment: Yes, onley for "Allow mock Locations" any other option i set in the DEV mode it's stay's in place, onley this one get's unchecked.

Comment: I got that, i also thought that was missing so i went and check everything but it is there.
Also no mather if start the app or not, or if i have ANY app running or not the "Allow mock Locations" still get's automaticly unchecked.

Comment: I realize this answer did not fix your issue, but I edited it to contain the follow up information from my comments for possible future help for others. I cleaned up the comments, as they are now integrated in the answer.

Comment: It is possible to modify this setting with command lines as your phone's rooted. Maybe it works, or u can make the config file read-only so nothing can turn it off.